# Why isn't my kernel extension writing to kernel.log

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extension, xnu

I have a simple kernel extension:

```
kern_return_t HelloWorld_start (kmod_info_t *ki, void * d) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}

kern_return_t HelloWorld_stop (kmod_info_t * kid, void * d) {
    printf("Goodbye World\n");
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which I'm compiling and loading via:

```
sudo kextload HelloWorld.kext
```

And it appears in the kextstat listing:

```
...
  129    0 0xffffff7f80fac000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction (85.2) <123 6 4 3 1>
  130    0 0xffffff7f80fb0000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction (85.2) <123 5 4 3 1>
  132    0 0xffffff7f807c6000 0x2000     0x2000     sk-r-d.HelloWorld (1) <4>
```

However, I have nothing in kernel.log (or system.log) - I should be seeing my printf() statements. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure your kext isn't accidentally being treated as a C++ (IOKit) kext? If it is, the start/stop won't be called.

Comment: Perhaps I selected the wrong template within xcode. I'll check tonight, thanks.

Comment: No, I definitely selected IOKit driver.

Comment: that's your problem then, if you want to use start/stop functions you'll need to use the "Generic Kernel Extension" template.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the console app doesn't seem to display printf messages from kexts, but the log console program does.

I've had success with the following magic words...

`log stream --predicate 'eventMessage contains "YourMatchingPatternHere"'`

This will produce a filtered stream showing only messages that match your predefined pattern.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1 debug=0x22"
```

Comment: Please use code block for code snippet in your answer. A better answer would also include an explanation on why this code line is the answer to the OP question.

Comment: Please also explain the code intead of posrting only code.